# Template Metaprogramming Discriminated Union

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, variant-type

`std::variant` and `boost::variant` do not require the types involved to be unique, but lose some functionality when types repeat.

I'm trying to create a simple type that has a fixed number of cases (`std::variant` and `boost::variant` are variadic) and has an elimination form that approximates the look and feel of `match`/`case`.

Here's a sum type with two variants in OCaml:

```
type red_or_blue_int = Red of int | Blue of int
```

and here's a `match` statement:

```
match r_or_b with
| Red r -> string_of_int r
| Blue b -> string_of_int b
```

That is more or less the syntax that I'm trying to emulate.

The syntax that I did manage to get looks like this:

```
BinaryPatternMatch<std::string, int, int, decltype(on_left), decltype(on_right)>::match(
      &inr,
      on_left,
      on_right
    )
```

where `on_left` and `on_right` would typically be lambdas. I'm not sure how to set up the deduction so that the types can be omitted.

Here's the header file:

```
#ifndef BINARY_SUM_HPP
#define BINARY_SUM_HPP

#include <cstring>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <cassert>

namespace binary_sum {

/* is_decayed */
template <class T>
struct is_decayed {
  static constexpr bool value =
    std::is_same<T, typename std::decay<T>::type>::value;
};
/* end_is_decayed */

/* is_initializer_list */
template <class T>
struct is_initializer_list {
  static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <class T>
struct is_initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> {
  static constexpr bool value = true;
};
/* end is_initializer_list */

template <class Left, class Right>
class Either {
public:
  virtual bool is_left() = 0;
  virtual bool is_left() const = 0;
};

template <class Left, class Right>
class InLeft : public Either<Left, Right> {
protected:
  Left left;

  template <class T>
  static constexpr bool enable_from_left_ctor =
    std::is_convertible<T, Left>::value &&
    is_decayed<T>::value &&
    (!(is_initializer_list<T>::value));
public:

  bool is_left() override {
    return true;
  }

  bool is_left() const override {
    return true;
  }

  template <
    class T,
    class = typename std::enable_if<enable_from_left_ctor<T>>::type
  >
  InLeft(T&& t) : left(t) {}

  InLeft(InLeft<Left, Right>&& t) : left(std::move(t.left)) {}

  InLeft(const InLeft<Left, Right>& t) : left(t.left) {}
};

template <class Left, class Right>
class InRight : public Either<Left, Right> {
protected:
  Right right;

  template <class T>
  static constexpr bool enable_from_right_ctor =
    std::is_convertible<T, Right>::value &&
    is_decayed<T>::value &&
    (!(is_initializer_list<T>::value));
public:
  bool is_left() override {
    return false;
  }

  bool is_left() const override {
    return false;
  }

  template <
    class T,
    class = typename std::enable_if<enable_from_right_ctor<T>>::type
  >
  InRight(T&& t) : right(t) {}

  InRight(InRight<Left, Right>&& t) : right(t.right) {}

  InRight(const InRight<Left, Right>& t) : right(t.right) {}
};



template <class Res, class Left, class Right, class LeftBranch, class RightBranch>
struct BinaryPatternMatch {
  static Res match(const Either<Left, Right> *e, LeftBranch lb, RightBranch rb) {
    assert(e != nullptr);
    if (e->is_left()) {
      return lb(*(static_cast<const InLeft<Left, Right> *>(e)));
    } else {
      return rb(*(static_cast<const InRight<Left, Right> *>(e)));
    }
  }
};

};
#endif
```

And here's the corresponding (minimal) test suite:

```
// binary sum

#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "binary_sum.hpp"
#include <string>

#define UNUSED(x) \
  ((void)(x))

using namespace binary_sum;

TEST(BinarySum, InLeftConstr1) {
  InLeft<int, int> inl(4.0);
  ASSERT_EQ(inl.is_left(), true);
  auto on_left = [](const InLeft<int, int>& x) {
    UNUSED(x);
    return std::string("LEFT");
  };
  auto on_right = [](const InRight<int, int>& x) {
    UNUSED(x);
    return std::string("RIGHT");
  };
  std::string patres(
    BinaryPatternMatch<std::string, int, int, decltype(on_left), decltype(on_right)>::match(
      &inl,
      on_left,
      on_right
    )
  );
  ASSERT_STREQ(
    "LEFT",
    patres.c_str()
  );
}

TEST(BinarySum, InLeftConstr2) {
  InLeft<int, int> inl{4.0};
  ASSERT_EQ(inl.is_left(), true);
}

TEST(BinarySum, InRight1) {
  InRight<int, int> inr(4.0);
  ASSERT_EQ(inr.is_left(), false);
  auto on_left = [](const InLeft<int, int>& x) {
    UNUSED(x);
    return std::string("LEFT");
  };
  auto on_right = [](const InRight<int, int>& x) {
    UNUSED(x);
    return std::string("RIGHT");
  };
  std::string patres(
    BinaryPatternMatch<std::string, int, int, decltype(on_left), decltype(on_right)>::match(
      &inr,
      on_left,
      on_right
    )
  );
  ASSERT_STREQ(
    "RIGHT",
    patres.c_str()
  );
}
```

The project was build using two Makefiles, one handling `gtest` and one for the main project. They aren't terrible idiomatic, `CMake` would probably be a better choice here. They aren't really the main subject of the review, but are here for the sake of completeness/reproducibility.

```
# Makefile

CC ?= clang
CXX ?= clang++

# our values come first, so they can be overridden
CFLAGS ?=
CPPFLAGS := -Igtest/include $(CPPFLAGS)
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++14 -g -O2 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -fsanitize=address $(CXXFLAGS)
LDFLAGS  := -fsanitize=address -L. -lgtest -lgtest_main -lpthread $(LDFLAGS)

# ugly, ugly rule. call ourselves with the libgtest in order
# to prevent the dependency from appearing in $^

binary_sum: binary_sum.cpp.o
    $(MAKE) libgtest.a
    $(MAKE) libgtest_main.a
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

%.cpp.o : %.cpp $(wildcard *.hpp)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<

clean:
    $(RM) $(wildcard *.cpp.o) binary_sum
    $(MAKE) -f gtest.mak clean

libgtest.a:
    $(MAKE) -f gtest.mak $@

libgtest_main.a:
    $(MAKE) -f gtest.mak $@
```

and for building `gtest` and depositing its artifacts in the local directory.

```
# gtest.mak

GTEST_SRC ?= /usr/src/gtest
GTEST_INCLUDE ?= /usr/include/gtest

CPPFLAGS := -isystem -I$(dirname $(GTEST_HEADERS)) -I$(GTEST_SRC) $(CPPFLAGS)
CXXFLAGS := -g -Wall -Wextra $(CXXFLAGS)
# specifically override link-time options
LDFLAGS :=

GTEST_HEADERS ?= $(wildcard $(GTEST_INCLUDE)/*.h) $(wildcard $(GTEST_INCLUDE)/internal/*.h)

GTEST_SRCS ?= $(wildcard $(GTEST_SRC)/*.cc) $(wildcard $(GTEST_SRC)/*.h)

gtest-all.o : $(GTEST_SRCS) $(GTEST_HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $(GTEST_SRC)/src/gtest-all.cc

gtest_main.o : $(GTEST_SRCS) $(GTEST_HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $(GTEST_SRC)/src/gtest_main.cc

libgtest.a : gtest-all.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

libgtest_main.a : gtest-all.o gtest_main.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

clean:
    $(RM) gtest-all.o gtest_main.o libgtest.a libgtest_main.a
```

Comment: IIRC, std::variant can have multiple equal types, but accessing them is only allowed through std::get with index specialization.

Comment: @Incomputable, you are absolutely correct. Some functionality like `std::holds_alternative` is ill-formed if the type appears more than once, so a `std::variant` with repeating types has less functionality, but nothing stops you from creating one.

Comment: I actually worked on a paper that involved pattern matching in C++. We couldn't get a nice syntax because return type deduction in lambdas is inconvenient for such a case.

Comment: (For all I know, Incomputable could *be* Michael Park, but...) if you haven't seen [MPark.Patterns](https://github.com/mpark/patterns#mparkpatterns) it is totally worth a look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to fix your template deduction is: You have a function you're calling with certain arguments that you want to deduce the types of, right? So make that function into a template! That is, take your current:

```
template <class Res, class Left, class Right, class LeftBranch, class RightBranch>
struct BinaryPatternMatch {
  static Res match(const Either<Left, Right> *e, LeftBranch lb, RightBranch rb) {
    assert(e != nullptr);
    if (e->is_left()) {
      return lb(*(static_cast<const InLeft<Left, Right> *>(e)));
    } else {
      return rb(*(static_cast<const InRight<Left, Right> *>(e)));
    }
  }
};
```

and rewrite it so that the function is a template:

```
namespace BinaryPatternMatch {
  template <class Res, class Left, class Right, class LeftBranch, class RightBranch>
  Res match(const Either<Left, Right> *e, LeftBranch lb, RightBranch rb) {
    assert(e != nullptr);
    if (e->is_left()) {
      return lb(*(static_cast<const InLeft<Left, Right> *>(e)));
    } else {
      return rb(*(static_cast<const InRight<Left, Right> *>(e)));
    }
  }
};
```

This immediately lets you rewrite your test cases as e.g.

```
std::string patres(
  BinaryPatternMatch::match<std::string, int, int, decltype(on_left), decltype(on_right)>(
    &inr,
    on_left,
    on_right
  )
);
```

and then you can drop any explicit parameters that are deducible:

```
std::string patres(
  BinaryPatternMatch::match<std::string>(
    &inr,
    on_left,
    on_right
  )
);
```

The final step would be to provide template parameter `Res` with a *default value* of `decltype(lb(*(static_cast<const InLeft<Left, Right> *>(e))))` — of course using [`std::declval<LeftBranch>()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) in place of `lb`, and so on.

---

Why do you want your lambdas to take e.g. `const InLeft<int, int>& x` instead of just `int x`? It seems to me that the lambda shouldn't care that the int it's receiving is a "left int"; all it needs to care about is the actual integer value. The only reason I can think of to tag the lambda with the "leftness" of its parameter type would be if you were going to actually *use* that information for overload resolution. That is, it would be nice to make this kind of thing work:

```
int result1 = 
  BinaryPatternMatch::match(
    &inr,
    [](const Left<int>& x) { return x + 1; },
    [](const Right<int>& x) { return x + 2; }
  )
);
int result2 = 
  BinaryPatternMatch::match(
    &inr,
    [](const Right<int>& x) { return x + 2; },
    [](const Left<int>& x) { return x + 1; }
  )
);
assert(result1 == result2);
```

But [I don't advise trying to make that work](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/06/12/perennial-impossibilities/#detect-the-first-argument-type-of-a-function), because it would fall flat on its face when confronted with the *perfectly reasonable* code

```
int result2 = 
  BinaryPatternMatch::match(
    &inr,
    [](const auto& x) { /* Don't make me write out long types! */ }
    ...
  )
);
```

---

Speaking of passing lambda arguments in-line... notice that your test cases are testing *only* the situation where the lambda arguments are lvalues (e.g. `on_left`). You don't have any tests for the more expected situation where the lambda arguments are prvalues (e.g. `[](Left<int>) { }`). You should definitely have some tests for that.

The closer your tests resemble real life, the fewer bugs you'll have — and you might even discover some new usage patterns that end up informing your API design!  (For example, you might discover that `Left<int> x` would be a much more convenient parameter declaration than `const InLeft<int, int>& x`... and then think about how to implement it.)

---

Speaking of which, you have no tests for `Either<A,B>` at all! That's surely a problem. Once you try using `Either`, you might realize that there's no good way to create an `Either` on the stack, and no way to dynamically reassign an `Either` from "left" to "right" without doing a new heap allocation.

If you're doing this for real code, instead of as a [[reinventing-the-wheel]] exercise, you should probably stop and go back to `std::variant`, where you can already do things like

```
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> auto overload(Ts... ts) { return overloaded<Ts...>{ts...}; }

template<class T> struct Left { T value; };
template<class T> struct Right { T value; };
using Either = std::variant<Left<int>, Right<int>>;

Either e = Left<int>{42};
std::string result = std::visit(overload(
    [](Left<int> x) { return "left " + std::to_string(x.value); },
    [](Right<int> x) { return "right " + std::to_string(x.value); }
), e);
```

That's the sort of syntax you're competing with when you try to roll your own pattern-matching.